# how to use semi_join function properly

Tags: r

I have two files.

```
 The first one looks like below,
    > data.frame(head(Becker))
                                     Becker
      1                  ABACK BACK A+ (BACK)
      2             ABACUS ABACUS ~- (ABACUS)
      3          ABANDGN ABANDON A+ ( BANDON)
      4     ABANDONED ABANDON A+ (BANDON) +ED
      5   ABANDONING ABANDON A+( BANDON) +ING
      6 ABANOONMENT ABANDON A+( BANDON) #MENT

  The second file looks like
        > data.frame(head(unique))
                         Word
                 1      Aback
                 2     carful
                 3  basketful
                 4 meaningful
                 5     boxful
                 6    armsful

  My ideal output 
  1      ABACK BACK A+ (BACK)
```

That is, I only wanted to extract words(including the neighbor words) that are present in the both files.

I read similar questions and I learned about semi_join function.
However, I kept getting the error message. Here is my code and the error message.
Could you anyone help me how to apply this function properly? or should I use different functions? If so, which function should I use? 
Thank you.

```
 semi_join(Becker, unique, by=c("Becker"="Word"))

         Becker                    <= output
         1     as

       Warning message:
 Column `Becker`/`Word` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character 
  vector
```

Comment: Please provide sample usable data for both frames, preferably `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` (for each).

Comment: Look for the `fuzzyjoin` package.

Comment: `semi_join` doesn't mean pattern-matching, it's a method for filtering (in a sense) but not adding columns from the second frame. Also, you have `factor`s, you might need to convert to `character` for other work.